# Visual Studio 2012 - removal functions using OpenGL (GLU, GLUT), in separate files

Tags: c++, oop, opengl, visual-studio-2012, project

I need to move some functions using the standard methods of OpenGL in a separate file for convenience. For example, I have this:

```
void moveCamera( float pp1, float pp2, float pp3, float pp4, float eX, float eY, float eZ)
{
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(pp1, pp2, pp3, pp4);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (eX, eY, eZ, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I read that all .cpp files of the project (at least included in the solution VS), is related to each other (correct me if I misunderstood), ie, the main file (the one that contains main () / _tmain ()) should see the rest and automatically included in the program code. Right?

However, if I try to make plans, and just create a file in the solution, where all of these features stand, it says that the functions OpenGL is undefined.

UPD. After trying to apply advices that I got here I have this picture:
[image]

Seems I have done something wrong. But what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the opengl headers in this other file.

Answer (score 1):

every .cpp file should have its header file (.h) where you just *define* its functions. In .cpp you *declare* them (you write what exactly they do).

> I (as a beginner) read that all .cpp files of the project (at least
>   included in the solution VS), is related to each other (correct me if
>   I misunderstood), ie, the main file (the one that contains main () /
>   _tmain ()) should see the rest and automatically included in the program code.

In order .cpp files to see each other you should include at the top the .h header file of the .cpp you want. Otherwise they do not see each other by default!
You should also include all the other libraries you want at every .cpp.

Here you should include OPENGL library.

Ask me again if i wasn't clear

Comment: Thank you for advice and sorry for such a late comment. I had tried to use your solution but still have troubles. Please, see the illustration which I have attached to my question today.

Comment: inside funx.cpp add 
    #include <GL/glut.h>
i think it should be ok